# Aligning numbers in array

Tags: align, matrices, arrays

What am I doing wrong here?:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{array}{c|c c c c c}
   & R & U & \rho & \eta & \alpha \\
  \hline
  \mathrm{L} & 1 & 1 & -3 & -1 & 0 \\
  \mathrm{M} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \mathrm{T} & 0 & -1 & -1 & -2 & 1 
\end{array}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope someone can help! And yes, I have seen some of the other similar questions, but I can't seem to get it to work. I want the numbers in the columns to be aligned under each other.

Comment: Using `{c|r r r r r}` might be good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had suggested in my comment to use `{c|r r r r r}` as the specifier for the array.  However, one may not like the fact that the numbers are right aligned relative to the letters above.  While a bit inconvenient, one can accomplish centered numbers in the array, if one laps the negative signs to the left, allowing enough array column separation.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\arraycolsep 1.5ex
\begin{array}{c|c c c c c}
   & R & U & \rho & \eta & \alpha \\
  \hline
  \mathrm{L} & 1 & 1 & \llap{$-$}3 & \llap{$-$}1 & 0 \\
  \mathrm{M} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \mathrm{T} & 0 & \llap{$-$}1 & \llap{$-$}1 & \llap{$-$}2 & 1 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here is the `{c|r r r r r}` approach, in which the letters are right-aligned with the numeric entries... slightly less visually appealing in my mind.

[image]

p.s.  Since you weren't aligning anything, I replaced the `align` environment with `equation`.

Comment: What if I wanted to achieve the same thing, but instead using a matrix environment such as pmatrix?

Comment: @CarstenGade That's a different question `;^)`

Comment: Do you know the answer to it?

Comment: @CarstenGade What I had in mind would not work with the horizontal and vertical rules, so I don't have something ready for you without a bit of thought and luck.

Comment: @StevenSegletes I can maybe live without the horizontal and vertical rules then; say I wanted just the numbers in a matrix, and then show a couple of steps of reducing the matrix - how can I put multiple matrices next to each other in one equation? Is equation the right environment for this or align?

Comment: @CarstenGade Without the rules, my `tabstackengine` package provides a `\ensurestackMath{\tabularCenterstack{rrrrr}{1&1&-3&-1&0\\0&0&1&1&1}}` macro for example, but that is not an environment.  I'm not sure how do force right alignments using the `amsmath` environments.